# Google Script Activate Sheet based on Reference Cell

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to activate a sheet based on a reference cell. For example, based on a formula I have in cell J13, it will change between Sheet 2, Sheet 3, or Sheet 4. This would then tell the script which sheet to run a script to hide rows. The row hiding works well, I just need the reference to work. It seems something close to:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetByName('Sheet 2');
```

But I want the 'Sheet 2' to be dynamic based on the value in cell J13.

Comment: So read the value of `Range`  "J13" into where you have written `'Sheet 2'`? Use the in-editor autocomplete and the handy-dandy Help ->Documentation menu to learn the language you are using.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'm not very experienced with this and their documentation doesn't make much sense to me, hence me asking the question on a forum.

Comment: Look up the class `Range`. Also the class `Sheet`. From a `Sheet`, you can get a `Range`. From a `Range`, you can get a value.